# Determine whether a macro is recorded and has not be modified by people

Tags: vba, excel

I want to determine if a macro is recorded by Excel "Record Macro", and if possible, if it has been modified by people.

There are some clues about it. For instance,

1) a recorded macro ALWAYS starts by

```
Sub m()
'
' m Macro
'

'
    first line
    ...
End Sub
```

(Note that sometimes, user name may be recorded after `m Macro`)

2) a recorded macro ALWAYS appear in a standard module

3) a recorded macro NEVER has a variable, a condition, a loop, or a procedure call

From the syntax of the sub, we can not be 100% sure to say a macro is recorded, because we can always follow word by word and write manually a same function. We cannot be 100% sure if a recorded macro is not modified, because people can well manually change a value or an index. However, are there more clues (like what I listed) to improve this confidence percentage?

Otherwise, is there any other mechanism than syntax to determine this?

Comment: I'm not so sure about your goal, but I would add a "clue": a recorded macro has a lot of "Select"...

Comment: I think a module is added each time, that combined with the typical formatting shown above could give you enough to code a trigger for detecting a macro being recorded. In terms of whether a macro has been edited, the only approach I can think of is storing the code from the VBE for the method in question and checking/monitoring whether it changes. As an aside, I think recorded macros can have loops.

Comment: @Will how possible can a recorded macro have loops?

Comment: What's the purpose of knowing whether the macro was recorded or hand written? What if someone only modifies the right hand side of a recorded macro's expression? That would become a false positive... Ps. recorded macros will not have loops.

Comment: SoftTimur - when changing object control settings I'm sure I've seen it before - maybe not, might be imagining it

Comment: @Will I really would hope loops could be recorded... Please provide more details if you recall later...

Comment: Why would you ever need to know this information?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: **No**

I could write a sub to look *exactly* like a recorded one - so you wouldn't know the difference.

Similarly, a less experienced user might record macros and then copy/paste the bits they need into another macro - so it would still look like a recorded macro.

---

The nearest thing you could have to this is an event driven macro to track any changes in the VBProject for the workbook - but anyone working in the VBE will more than likely have the know-how to get around that anyway.